# How to pass collection<?> over JAX-WS web service

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, cxf

In my project I need to write a web service which will receive `Collection<?>` as a parameter.. I am using apache CXF.. After I have written the service method I am unable to test it using SOAP UI (It is not generating any request).. My question is - Is it possible to receive `Collection<?>` over web service? I need to receive Collection of any object type.. Please help..

Comment: Yes it's possible. What exactly is your question? Where is the code you're working with? What problems is it giving you?

Answer (score -1):

You need to work directly with [SOAP messages](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/).